# Language of record owner email change

Tags: apex, email, dmloptions, record-owner

We have built some custom owner change logic for tasks, leads and opportunities, but now I want to know how is the language of the email decided?

Example code:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlo.OptAllOrNone = true;
dmlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = this.sendNotificationEmail;
Database.update(myOpportunity, dmlo);
```

We have the same code for all 3 objects(Tasks, Leads and Opportunities).

What I figured out is:

- Leads and Opportunity email language is defined by the language of the new owner
- Task email language is defined by the language of the running user

But is there any official documentation on how the email language is chosen?

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gnsEAAQ?